# error 500 http on prestashop bankwire module

Tags: prestashop, linker-errors

I met some trouble while using prestashop. In fact I just set up my own shop and I met some trouble using the bankwire. when somebody do confirm its order, it turns into a error 500 instead of displaying the confirmation of the order.

I'm on php 5.3 here is the adress of the website. www.omega-nutrition.fr

Answer (score 0):

you will probably need to provide more information. Check the server error logs and also make sure that your permissions are set at 755 (or 644). Make sure that you clear the cache and cookies if the permission needs to be changed.

Also, I think if you have the Collisimo module installed and do not need it, try to uninstall it and that might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `/logs/date_exception.log`

If you have this error:

```
Can't load Order status at line 167 in file classes/PaymentModule.php
```

**(prestashop 1.6)**

You have to insert all default order status :

- ps_order_state
- ps_order_state_lang

dump theses original tables from fresh install and import into your database